# Diffeomorphism between complex hyperbolic space and unit ball

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $h$ be the bilinear map:
$$h:\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\to \mathbb{C},\ \ \ \ (z,w)\mapsto -z_0\overline{w_0}+\sum_{i>0} z_i\overline{w_i}$$
and let $\mathfrak{I}:h(z,z)=-1$. There is an obvious left action of $S^1$ on $\mathfrak{I}$ and I wanna prove that $\mathfrak{I}/S^1$ is diffeomorphic to the open ball in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

**My attempt**

It's pretty clear that every element of $\mathfrak{I}/S^1$ can be written (almost) uniquely as:
$$z=(r_0,r_1e^{i\theta_1},...,r_ne^{i\theta_n})$$
so my idea was to define something like $z\mapsto (r_1,...,r_n,\theta_1,...,\theta_n)$, but this clearly works only if we suppose that $r_i\neq 0$ for every $i>0$  (otherwise things get a bit messy, because $\theta_i$ is not even well defined). Is this the right track?

Comment: Is the formula for $h$ correct, without conjugates? I don't see how $S^1$ acts on $\mathfrak{I}$ if this is not the case. (Or, is $\mathfrak{I}$ defined by $h(z,\bar{z})=-1$?)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I've corrected!

Comment: Suppose you were to replace $-$ with $+$ in the definition of $h$ and $\mathfrak{I}$. Do you understand why the quotient in this case would be diffeomorphic to $CP^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Z=(z_0,z)$ with $z_0 \in \Bbb C$ and $z \in \Bbb C^n$.
Then $h(Z,Z) = -1$ if and only if $|z_0|^2 = 1+ \|z\|^2$.
It follows that $z_0\neq 0$ whenever $Z \in \Im$ (and even that $|z_0| \geqslant 1$).
In this case, its equivalence class satisfies $[z_0,z] = [|z_0|, z z_0^{-1}|z_0|]$, and $(|z_0|, z z_0^{-1}|z_0|)$ is the unique representative whose first element is positive.
It follows that we have the following bijection
$$
z \in \Bbb C^n \longmapsto \left[\sqrt{1+\|z\|^2}, z\right] \in \Im/S^1.
$$
I leave you as an exercise that this is indeed a smooth diffeomorphism.
In particular, $\Im/S^1$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb C^n$.
It is now standard that $\Bbb C^n$ is diffeomorphic to a ball.
For instance, the map $u\in B(0;1) \mapsto \frac{u}{\sqrt{1-\|u\|^2}}\in \Bbb C^n$ is a diffeomorphism.
Since
$$
1 + \left\|\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-\|u\|^2}}\right\|^2 = \frac{1}{1-\|u\|^2},
$$
it follows that
$$
u \in B(0;1) \longmapsto \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\|u\|^2}}, \frac{u}{\sqrt{1-\|u\|^2}} \right] \in \Im/S^1
$$
is a diffeomorphism.